# Why is this on('resize') event triggered at load and not on window resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code wrapped in `$(document).ready(function(){});`:

```
var sizeMapContainer = function(n) {
    var w = $(window).innerHeight();
    var h = $('#sl-header-container').outerHeight();
    var f = $('.oev-form-container').outerHeight();
    var m = w - h - f;
   $('#map-container').outerHeight(m);
}
sizeMapContainer(1);
$(window).on('resize', sizeMapContainer(2));
```

Why is it that `sizeMapContainer` gets called twice when the page loads but not when I resize the window?

Comment: What is the point of the variable `n`.
It looks like its not being used at all in which case changing `$(window).on('resize', sizeMapContainer(2));` to `$(window).on('resize', sizeMapContainer);` will solve your problem because adding the parenthesis after a function will effectively call it in this case. Alternatively if you need that variable you will need to wrap it inside of another function, i.e. `$(window).on('resize', function(){sizeMapContainer(2)});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling the function, not binding the event to the function. It should be:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    sizeMapContainer(2);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please explain this a little? I was under the impression that the function gets called when the event happens.

Comment: The 2nd argument to `on` must be a function. `sizeMapContainer(2)` isn't a function, it CALLS the function at that time.

Answer (score 0):

This is the line with the issue

```
$(window).on('resize', sizeMapContainer(2));
```

The second argument to 'on' is a function that will be run when the 'resize' event occurs.  It's not expecting to be called with your (2) at the end. It's running your function sizeMapContainer() on the spot, rather than letting the 'resize' event decide when it happens. If you remove the (2) you'll get the sizeMapContainer() function firing when you resize.

```
function myName(){
    return "Aaron";
}

console.log( myName ); //gives you the function itself
console.log( myName() ); //gives you Aaron
```

So what he did was create an anonymous function that runs your function and passes the argument for you.

Hope that helps clear things up.